# Loop over an NSMutable Dictionary only returns last item

Tags: objective-c

```
//loop over alphabet and set the key values for addressbook
for(char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; a++){
        addressbook=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [addressbook setValue:@"$" forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", a]];
        NSLog(@"%@ value, %@ key", @"$",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", a]);

    }
}
//display the key values of addressbook
  for(NSString *key in addressbook){
    NSLog(@"%@ key, %@ value", key,[addressbook objectForKey:key]);
}
```

The first NSLog shows a working for loop

```
2012-02-27 16:02:31.886 Adresboek[4692:503] $ value, a key
2012-02-27 16:02:31.889 Adresboek[4692:503] $ value, b key
2012-02-27 16:02:31.890 Adresboek[4692:503] $ value, c key
.
.
.
2012-02-27 16:02:31.911 Adresboek[4692:503] $ value, x key
2012-02-27 16:02:31.912 Adresboek[4692:503] $ value, y key
2012-02-27 16:02:31.913 Adresboek[4692:503] $ value, z key
```

The second NSLog shows only the last element

```
2012-02-27 16:02:31.914 Adresboek[4692:503] z key, $ value
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, sure. You're creating a new `NSMutableDictionary` every time around the loop. Move the creation to before the loop.

```
for(char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; a++){
        addressbook=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];

addressbook=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
for(char a = 'a'; a <= 'z'; a++){
```

Comment: thanks I couldn't see the obvious, sometimes it helps if someone else looks at it.